# how to share Python's MongoClient in a ProcessPoolExecutor mixed ThreadPoolExecutor program

Tags: python, mongodb

since MongoClient is not fork-safe, but thread-safe, so i want share MongoClient in one process, but i dont't know how to share the variable. see the code below:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from pymongo import MongoClient

def run():
    executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=10)
    executor.map(process_task)
    executor.shutdown()

def process_task():
    client = MongoClient(mongouri)
    db = client["test"]


def thread_task():
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(10) as executor:
        executor.submit(real_task)


def real_task():
    # how to get the variable "client" defined in process_task function
   


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```